# Json response parsing using JavaScript Overlay Types in GWT

Tags: json, gwt

I have a query in parsing json response coming from server. We have used gson to serialize a list of objects to a json string in server. In gwt client, we have used JavaScript overlay types to parse it. So my gwt call from client looks like this

//Code snippet where json response is from list of obj from server.

```
jsonpReqBuiler.requestObject(url, new AsyncCallback<JsArray<MyJsoClass>>() {
           onSuccess(final JsArray<MyJsoClass> result) {
              ////Need a string equivalent of JsArray type to sore???
           }
}
```

We want to store the json response - JsArray into sqllite database as a string. Even though server responds with Json string, it has resulted as JsArray type after internal parsing, now I can store it as a string so that I can read and convert back??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
jsonpReqBuiler.requestObject(url, new AsyncCallback<JsArray<MyJsoClass>>() {
    onSuccess(final JsArray<MyJsoClass> result) {
        String json = new JSONArray(result).toString();
    }
}
```